# encodeURIComponent in AngularJS $http service

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

*I am new to AngularJS and trying to learn the ropes.*

I'm using the following line of code (untested mind you) to send an `item` of information to a server method that will then send an HTML email containing said `item`.

```
$http.post('/EmailItem', item);
```

My question is, do `item`'s property values go through `encodeURIComponent` before being sent?

**Bonus question:** Is there a better way of doing the post? `$resource` seems on the face of it to be more than what I need...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to encode the properties, `$http` does: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L758

As to the way of doing it.. This looks fine.  You can switch to `$resource` if have an object that needs a couple of REST things on the server, but `$http` works fine in simple situations.