# HTTP 400 (Bad Request) when making XHR from AngularJS webapp

Tags: javascript, http, angularjs

Working with a REST API and AngularJS I've ran into a problem where, when making a HTTP Get request, a `400 Bad request` error is returned.

Quoted from RFCs:

`The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.`

The URL is formed as so, `/target/url/id`. The ID being passed in is a fairly long string containing illegal characters, so encodeURIComponent is being used. An example:

`i-6a622da27%2F2013-09-20-09-25%2F4d610497-cfaa-42ec-8856-d5e0e2edd3ce%2F3b560f33-d5c8-4c0a-92c5-f892e4c30408`

I'm making the request with the following shortcut AngularJS GET.

```
  $http.get('/target/url' + encodeURIComponent(id))
  .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log('win');
  })
  .error(function () {
    console.log('fail');
  });
```

Chrome / Firefox just returns with a 400. What's strange is when the exact same request is made with a HTTP REST client, it behaves as expected. I've tried adding different headers to the request but with no effect.

I can't figure out what's different about the request being made from the browser or the HTTP client. The error itself is odd as the URL is definitely not malformed.

Comment: What are the requirements that makes a valid request?

Comment: @Bart only legal characters are used in the ID, hence `encodeURIComponent`. There are no auth headers or anything the server is expecting.

Comment: Could it be the service is trying to block browser access?

Comment: It's being used elsewhere by the browser without any problems.

Comment: Are you sure you’re not missing a slash after `/target/url`? If yes, try just dumping and comparing your traffic in both cases with a tool like Wireshark or `tcpdump`.

Comment: I have this same problem. It works with jQUery.ajax, but with angular's $http I get error 400.

Comment: Has someone found a solution for this issue yet?

Comment: @Arunster I never did, and I've not come across the issue since actually. It wasn't the missing slash either–that was a paste-fail. I think it might have been an encoding problem.

Comment: Thank you. I ask because we are seeing something similar in our application as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [encodeURIComponent in AngularJS $http service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825290/encodeuricomponent-in-angularjs-http-service)